# Motion Tracking Workspace problems

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view, video, tracking

Scene Setup

Set as Background
Sets the clip currently being edited as the camera background for all visible 3D Views. If there is no visible 3D Views or the Clip Editor is open in full screen, nothing will happen.

In the Motion Tracking tab, the "Set as Background" button sometimes works, sometimes does not.  Sometimes the clip is stored in my camera background, sometimes it's not.  I don't know why this happens.  Any clues?

Thank you.